# Decode JSON each array to PHP

Tags: php, json

I have some encoded json like this:

```
[
    {"title":"root", "link":"one"},
    {"title":"branch", "link":"two"},
    {"title":"leaf", "link":"three"}
]
```

I want to decode that JSON into PHP output like:

```
title   ||    link
root    ||    one
branch  ||    two
leaf    ||    three
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
$list = json_decode($json);
foreach ($list as $list => $value) {
    echo $list->title;
    echo $list->link;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is looping the keys and values seperated and than you tried to get the values from the keys of the stdClass, what you need to do is looping it as an object. I also used `json_decode($json_str, true)` to get the result as an array instead of an stdClass.

```
$json_str = '[{"title":"root","link":"one"},{"title":"branch","link":"two"},{"title":"leaf","link":"three"}]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_str, true);
foreach($json_decoded as $object)
{
    echo $object['title'];
    echo $object['link'];
}
```

Comment: but i tried to encode this link http://penanggulangankrisis.kemkes.go.id/ipaddress/api_ip.php and its says invalid foreach argument

i use json_decode(file_get_contents($url2), true);
and $url2 = "http://penanggulangankrisis.kemkes.go.id/ipaddress/api_ip.php";

Comment: @dennisramli var_dump the file_get_contents, what is the result? "null"?

Comment: no,, the result is not null @DevNiels

Answer (score 3):

try changing your foreach loop to this.

```
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->title."  ||  ";
        echo $value->link." ";
        echo nl2br("\n");
        }
```

Hope this Works for you.

Comment: instead of hardcoded spaces, you can use "\t"

Comment: "\t" is not allowed in php

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
$list = json_decode($json);
foreach ($list as $item) {
    echo $item->title . ' || ' . $item->link . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Would you like to extend the answer little bit more, for fellow programmers to understand, how it helps to solve the problem.